# how to make angular filters customizable and how to use them in javascript

Tags: filter, angularjs, controller

I have an array on my controller

```
$scope.arr = [......], a
```

nd in html I want to do

```
ng-repeat = "item in arr | color:'blue'" //this line works, filter done in the app.filter way.
```

where color is an attribute of all objects in arr.

How Do I make this color:'blue' customizable and sub in color:'red'?

also if I want to do controller filtering instead of html, what would be the syntax, right now I have

```
$scope.filteredArr = $filter('color')($scope.arr,'blue');
```

which is giving error

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/YpMKX/

posted fiddle, please remove -1

Comment: Could you share some live code (in plunker or jsFiddle). There is probably a very simple answer to your question but it is hard to help based on your description and limited amount of code.

Comment: "which is giving error". Why didn't you post the error here? This really helps.

Comment: thank you i am sure that its simple, I just cant seem to find my solution on ng org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize `color:'blue'` with any expression in the format `filter:expression`, so something like `color:myColor` would work fine provided a `color` filter has been defined and `myColor` exists in the current scope.

In your controller, you can do the same.

`$scope.filteredArr = $filter('color')($scope.arr,myColor);`

Here is an example based on your jsFiddle example.

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .filter('eyecolor', function () {
        return function ( people, color ) {
            var arr = [];
            for ( var i = people.length; i--; ) {
                if ( people[i].eyeColor === color ) {
                    arr.push( people[i] );
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
    })
    .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.desiredColor = 'Brown';
        $scope.people = [
            {       
                name: 'Bob',
                eyeColor: 'Brown'
            }, {
                name: 'Katherine',
                eyeColor: 'Yellow'
            }, {
                name: 'Chun',
                eyeColor: 'Black'
            }
        ];
        $scope.peopleFilter = $filter('eyecolor')( $scope.people, $scope.desiredColor );
    });
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">Color Desired:
        <input ng-model="desiredColor" /><br/>        
        <div ng-repeat="person in people | eyecolor: desiredColor">
            HTML filter: {{person.name}} has eye color {{person.eyeColor}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="person in peopleFilter">
            Controller filter: {{ person.name }} has eye color {{ person.eyeColor }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```